# Triangulate modifier setting matching triangulation pattern in fbx and glTF exports

Tags: mesh, modifiers, export, faces

Is there a way I can ensure that a model's triangulation pattern on a modifier will be the same as exporting it as a glTF(always triangulated) or fbx with the triangulate faces option?

I am not sure if the modifier options, beauty and clip match the triangulation of these exports?

I am interested in this for real time asset workflow.

Comment: Usually exporters have an option called "Apply modifiers" that should do what you're looking for. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Hi @Gorgious. I am not asking how to use modifiers on export, instead, what triangulate setting on modifiers matches the triangulation on export.

Comment: I've tested this before, and AFAICT none of the options are always the same as the triangulation shown in the viewport (which is what glTF exports).